# Global extension function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

Hey I want to make a class in kotlin that will hold all extension functions that I will use in a few places for example:

```
class DateUtils {
    //in this case I use jodatime
    fun Long.toDateTime() : DateTime = DateTime(this)
    fun String.toDateTime() : DateTime = DateTime.parse(this)
}


class SomeClassWithNoConnectionToDateUtils {
    fun handleDataFromServer(startDate: String) {
        someOtherFunction()
        //startDate knows about toDateTime function in DateUtils 
        startDate.toDateTime().plusDays(4)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to perform such operation

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Having your extensions inside a `DateUtils` class will make them available for use only inside the `DateUtils` class.

If you want the extensions to be global, you can just put them on the top level of a file, without putting them inside a class.

```
package com.something.extensions

fun Long.toDateTime() : DateTime = DateTime(this)
fun String.toDateTime() : DateTime = DateTime.parse(this)
```

And then import them to use them elsewhere like so:

```
import com.something.extensions.toDateTime

val x = 123456L.toDateTime()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the noob question but I'm new at kotlin coming from Java.how can I use data in a constructor to use in the function?

Comment: No worries, it was a perfectly reasonable question. Have fun with Kotlin :)